# how i can select a one certain value from database

Tags: java, mysql, select, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to check if there is an entry in my database with a name that I pass to the method
and if there is, then return the true, else false

I'm tried using JdbcTemplate, but i don't sure i use the right method
(I need to do this with JdbcTemplate or JdbcOperations)

```
@Override
    public boolean searchRecordInDatabase(ExchangeRateRecord record) {
        String currencyInDB = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT Spot FROM spots WHERE Currency='" + (" " + record.getCurrency()) + "'", String.class);
        return currencyInDB.trim().isEmpty();
    }
```

Comment: You can do a 
`select count(1) FROM spots WHERE Currency= ` .. Count will return 1 to more if the record exists.

Comment: `select count(1)` ? @KennethClark is that from the SQL optimizer dark days where it was faster when using `COUNT(1)` ?  The trick will not matter annymore nowadays..

Comment: bwahahah .. @RaymondNijland .. i've seen some things. Good practice anyway

Comment: @Kenneth Clark 
Do you mean sql request?

Comment: `int noOfRecords = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( select count ... , Integer.class );`

Comment: @KennethClark
in fact, there are no differences from my method

Comment: @qwerty The difference is that the data won't actually be retrieved from the database, so the query will resolve faster on the Java side.

Comment: I'm actually a bit more concerned by the SQLi in here.

Comment: @EvanKnowles
why?

Comment: *"i've seen some things. Good practice anyway"* Well `COUNT(1)` it's slightly faster in MySQL 5.6 atleast  @KennethClark but seams its really a mirco optimisation. ->  [COUNT(*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b913a1/13) vs [COUNT(1)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b913a1/10) as the parser seams to be able to parse `COUNT(1)` slightly faster..  Also when reading `COUNT(1)` somebody else can read it as literal Count `1` consider [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b913a1/15), `COUNT(*)` is much better practice in mine opinion as it is more clear what it does but matter of taste i guess